# In Python, how do you join a dataframe with a dictionary based on the key?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe:

[image]

And I also have a dictionary which basically counters the number of members in the team. For example, Mike and Stella are on Frank's team so under a new column "Number of Team Mates" would be 2.

```py
team_dict = {'Frank': 2, 'Jake': 1, 'Rando': 1, 'Susan': 1, 'Steven': 1, 'Dan': 1}
```

Final result:

[image]

Comment: Please read and edit your question... [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How is the dataframe represented in Python?

Comment: Convert the dict into a dataframe then join it the same way you would join 2 dataframes

Answer (score 2):

If you have `team_dict` that shows the number, you can use `map`:

```
df['Number of Team Mates'] = df['Team'].map(team_dict)
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Mike', 'Dave', 'Jason', 'Jack', 'Javier', 'Roberto', 'Stella'],
        'Team': ['Frank', 'Jake', 'Susan', 'Rando', 'Steven', 'Dan', 'Frank']}

team_dict = {'Frank': 2, 'Jake': 1, 'Rando': 1, 'Susan': 1, 'Steven': 1, 'Dan': 1}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Number of Team Mates'] = df['Team'].map(team_dict)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      Name    Team  Number of Team Mates
0     Mike   Frank                     2
1     Dave    Jake                     1
2    Jason   Susan                     1
3     Jack   Rando                     1
4   Javier  Steven                     1
5  Roberto     Dan                     1
6   Stella   Frank                     2
```

Comment: Oh wow. A big thank you. This worked!!!